# Are there any buses to Rocky Mountain House, Alberta, Canada?

Tags: canada, buses, alberta

Although [Greyhound.ca has a page on Rocky Mountain House](https://www.greyhound.ca/en/locations/terminal.aspx?city=723221), and [Rome2rio claims there are buses](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Red-Deer/Rocky-Mountain-House), I can't find any buses going to Rocky Mountain House and [according to this article, Greyhound no longer has service](http://www2.canada.com/life/greyhound+cuts+back+service+alberta/5247592/story.html?id=5247592).  The latter page also states that *Others will step in, said Trent Bancarz, a spokesman for Alberta Transportation.*.  [Alberta Canada Transportation](https://www.albertacanada.com/opportunity/living/transport-options.aspx#public-transportation) notes that long-distance buses are operated by Greyhound or [Red Arrow](http://www.redarrow.ca), but I can't find a connection there either.

Are there any buses to Rocky Mountain House, Alberta, Canada?

<sup>(My *actual* destination would be the Cline River Canyon trailhead along the [David Thompson Highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberta_Highway_11).  I assume there is no public transit on the latter, and I would hitch-hike from Rocky Mountain House; the road from Red Deer to Rocky Mountain House may be much less hitchhike-friendly, though.  I do not wish to rent a car because I do not wish to return to the trailhead)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Red Arrow has [service to Rocky Mountain House](http://www.redarrow.ca/red-arrow-connector-service), but only one round trip, and only on Tuesdays.</s>

<s>The Red Arrow Connector leaves Red Deer iHotel at 6:00 pm, after picking up at several other points in town, and reaches Rocky Mountain House at 7:15 pm.</s>

<s>The trip to Red Deer leaves Rocky Mountain House at 6:05 am and arrives at iHotel at 7:20 am, afterward stopping at several other points in Red Deer.</s>

<s>iHotel is the primary transfer point for buses going to and from Calgary and Edmonton. The buses stop in the west parking lot behind the hotel; you will see a Red Arrow sign. Based on the [schedule](http://www.redarrow.ca/Printable_Schedule), you should not have a very long wait to change buses, traveling in either direction.</s>

Red Arrow canceled its Rocky Mountain House service in June 2015. As of now, there seems to be *no* public transit between these two towns at all.

---

Of course, the town nearest to where you're really going is [Nordegg](http://www.travelnordegg.com/), and this town has no public transit services at all. From my searching, I also was unable to find any shuttle services, as are common in the U.S. The [hostel](http://www.hihostels.ca/westerncanada/1384/HI-Nordegg,_Shunda_Creek_Hostel.hostel) might know of such services; it may be worth giving them a call and asking if they know of anyone who can arrange a ride for you from Rocky Mountain House or Red Deer.

Comment: Good find.  I was considering to get to Nordegg / Cline River by hitch-hiking from Rocky Mountain House, which I thought should be easier than from Red Deer (smaller road and hopefully some tourist traffic heading to Banff).  The Nordegg hint is good too, although it'd still be 50 km to the trailhead.

Comment: Hitching out of Red Deer looks as painful as any other dual carriageway, but it ought not be excessively troublesome after you cross over the QEII highway.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your first trip out there I would strongly suggest changing your one-way plans and rent a car. That part of the country is very empty, I've driven for an hour on the David Thompson and not seen another vehicle. Unless you have a huge amount of time available, and don't mind walking most of the way carrying your own supplies (not many stores out there either) a vehicle is more-or-less essential. Cost won't be much different than the bus either. Econoboxes are rentable in the $30 / day range.

Comment: Hm, that surprises me — I thought the Canadian Rockies were very popular, with [3.3 million visitors per year to Banff alone](http://www.pc.gc.ca/docs/pc/attend/table3.aspx).  Does that not spill over to the surrounding areas?
(As another option, for the price of a 2 week car rental at 30$/day I could probably take a taxi from Jasper or Banff, and I wouldn't have to return to my starting point)

Comment: Banff is hugely popular, 90 minutes from Calgary on the Trans-Canada and served by Greyhound and other buses hourly. The Icefields Parkway ( Banff to Jasper ) is equally popular, some hotels on that route charge $2500 / night. RMH is 300km north, halfway between Red Deer and a road junction, and contains nothing of particular interest. The fact that there's only one bus per week there should tell you a lot.

Comment: I realise that my two wishes (avoiding the crowds + not having to travel by my own car) are in conflict.  Maybe there are buses from Jasper to Saskatchewan River Crossing.  Perhaps I'm wrong to extrapolate my European experience that there are enough people trying to avoid the crowds for there to be traffic on a road like the David Thompson (FWIW, [Google Streetview of the David Thomspon at Saskatchewan River Crossing does show some traffic](http://goo.gl/maps/hus45)).

Comment: Sask. River Crossing is on the Icefields Parkway, a rather busy road. Extrapolating any European experience  outside the Russian Steppes to backwater Alberta is a bit of a stretch. Go down that road on Google and ask yourself if you want to be there without a vehicle. I would not. Yes, there is some traffic. Depends on the day. Incidentally, if you do not want to return to the trailhead, how far to you plan to walk?